# Nginx redirect only change first part of URL after domain

Tags: redirect, nginx

I would like to change only the first part of the url on a group of pages.

Eg.

```
domain.com/change/this/that/other
```

to

```
domain.com/changed/this/that/other
```

in the example everything after and including this would be dynamic

I thought this would work

```
location ~* ^/change/(.*)$ {rewrite ^ http://domain.com/changed/$1 permanent; break;}
```

but doesnt

Comment: i got it working using return 301 instead but would still like to know why it doesnt work with rewrite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regex capture variables relate to rewrite block itself.

```
location ~* ^/change/(.*)$ {
     rewrite ^/change/(.*)$ http://example.com/changed/$1 permanent; 
     break;
}
```

You can see the examples: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: thanks for the clarification. The return 301 syntax is more readable so Ill stick with that one. Do you know if there is any advantage to either way?

Comment: I think you should use 301 redirect in that case if you want to inform search engines and other robots about permanent changing of the url. And you should remove permanent directive if you want to make rewrite process invisible.